# SSI call inside CGI?

Tags: html, cgi, ssi

is it possible to place a Server Side Include within a CGI script?
Is there any alternatives to doing this?

Comment: What would be the point? What do you hope to accomplish with this? You already have the ability to perform dynamic actions in a CGI script, which is what SSI is usually used for.

Comment: http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/adashimar/ssi.shtml